# Requirements for using vjslib

Tags: c#, wpf, compression, zip, visualj#

I need to create zip and unzip logic for a WPF application without using any external Libraries.So,I used vjslib  instead.

now,I need to know what are the requirements for my WPF application to successfully zip and unzip files.apart form having .net 3.5 sp1(which is already installed in the client system).

do i need to install anything more in client to use vjslib(other than .Net Framework 3.5 sp1)  in WPF??

Bcoz I got many 
           " Error: 'Could not load file or assembly vjslib' " in Goolgle Search.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use vjslib.  vjslib is for a discontinued language called Visual J#.  You don't want to use that.  Remove any references you have to it and instead reference a compression library for dealing with zip files.  There's no reason not to use libraries, that's the whole point of .net  You just need to make sure they're included in your application when you distribute it.

Comment: There's some irony here, vjslib *is* an external library.  It is a separate download and not part of the .NET framework.  Obsolete too, Visual J# is discontinued since VS2005.  Don't sweat the small stuff.